Kotlin generic lambda Type mismatch. Required: nothing
I have a problem using Kotlin generic and lambda.
Basically I want my interface to have a lambda function on a generic type.
My goal is to make multiple implementation of my class A and then use the abstract to put them in a list of example.
Here is some sample code showing what I want to do.
interface A<T : B, U : C> {
    fun where(rdm: (T) -> U): A<T, U>
}

interface B {
    fun debugB(): C
}

interface C


class D : B {
    override fun debugB(): F {
        return F()
    }

    fun toto() {
    }
}

class F : C


class test : A<D, F> {
    override fun where(rdm: (D) -> F): test {
        return this
    }
}

class main() {
    init {
        val test: A<*, *> = test()
        test.where { q -> q.debugB() }
    }
}

In that exemple I tried to put A<*, *> but the problem is that I get an error message when I try to do test.where { q -> q.debugB() }: Type mismatch. Required: Nothing found: C.
I find this really weird since it is able to resolve the type of q to B but it can find the correct return type.
(I tried in out and none of them work.)

The asterisks you put in for the types mean the type is unknown, so you can’t input anything. It basically means, “do not accept input”. The compiler can’t know whether the type of your input is acceptable.

Thank @Tenfour04 and I understand, but it don't really help me to find any fix :/

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you make it interface A<out T : B, in U : C> then you can have val test: A<B, C> = test() as A<B, C>.

But why won't you simply remove the : A<*, *> part? It seems the main problem is that you upcasted your object to something not very useful.

It’s hard to answer because it’s hard to tell what you’re trying to do. Putting those asterisks in is a deliberate action that prevents the code from accepting input. Why are you doing that if you don’t want that to happen? We can tell you to just remove it, but it seems there is a higher level problem having to do with your overall goals here. An AB problem.

Hey @broot, sorry if I wasn't clear about why I was trying to do this, I edited the question. My goal is to make several implementations of my class A, then use the abstract A to store them in a list for examples. The problem with your solution is that ```val testis of typeTestand not the abstract typeA. Therefore, I cannot use it in a class that takes A`` as a parameter.

Hey @Tenfour04, sorry if I wasn't clear about why I was trying to do this, I edited the question. My goal is to make several implementations of my class A, then use the abstract A to store them in a list for examples. The problem with your solution is that ```val test`` is of type Test and not the abstract type A. Therefore, I cannot use it in a class that takes A as a parameter.

@BasileLamarque So do I understand your case correctly that you have multiple implementations of A with different T and U and you need to store them in a single list? If this is the case, then how we could know whether the lambda passed to where returns the correct type for a specific A implementation? I suspect this is the root problem in your code design. If test is A<D, F>, then it can't be A<B, C>, because its where requires to return F specifically, not just any C.

Ah, you probably meant that T.debugB() always returns U, so it is always safe to do: where { q -> q.debugB() }. Is this correct?

Not sure why you are explicitly setting the asterisks in the val test object. By doing so, you are preventing the test object from accessing to the interface B.
Allow the compiler to infer the types by simply removing the type when calling the constructor.
val test = Test()
test.where { q -> q.debugB() }


Sorry if I wasn't clear about why I was trying to do this, I edited the question. My goal is to make several implementations of my class A, then use the abstract A to store them in a list for examples. The problem with your solution is that ```val testis of typeTestand not the abstract typeA. Therefore, I cannot use it in a class that takes A`` as a parameter.

You can define the type of the variable test to be A<D, F> instead of using the star projection, which is upcasting into something unusable.
Note, if you create a list of different A implementations, they will have to use the same types for T and U, since T and U are invariant. You could make T and U contravariant (in), but that doesn’t really help since a list’s type is covariant. For example, you cannot have a Test<D, F> in a List<A<B, C>>, because an A<D, F> is not a subtype of an A<B, C>.

Hey thank for your answer, I understand the first part indeed. For the second part you basically saying that there is no way for me to do it right ?

If your goal is to have a List<A<B, C>> that holds A<D, F>s and maybe also As of other types, and you want to be able to retrieve items from the list to call where on them, then that is logically impossible, and also the compiler will prevent you from doing it.

Your test class currently doesn’t use the rdm parameter. If it did, it might invoke the rdm function to get an instance of F. But if you were iterating your list and the compiler actually let you do this, you would be passing a parameter rdm that returns Cs, not Fs.  In test.where() you might try to use a feature of F from something returned by invoking rdm but it has returned some other subtype of C instead leading to ClassCastException. This is why it doesn’t logically make sense and the compiler will prevent it.
